# Laravel Request Conversion

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, namespaces, laravel-5.4

Can anyone help me convert this and help a noob learn the difference.

```
/**
     * User Delete Account via Profile
     *
     * @access protected
     * @return void
     *
     */
    protected function deleteProfile(Request $request) {
        $this->validate($request, [
            'confirmation' => 'required',
            'password' => 'required',
        ]);
        $usr = User::findOrFail(Auth::user()->id);
        if (Hash::check($request->password, $usr->password)) {
            Auth::logout();
            // Removes UserID from Torrents if any and replaces with System UserID (0)
            foreach(Torrent::where('user_id', '=', $usr->id)->get() as $tor) {
                $tor->user_id = 0;
                $tor->save();
            }
            // Removes UserID from Comments if any and replaces with System UserID (0)
            foreach(Comment::where('user_id', '=', $usr->id)->get() as $com) {
                $com->user_id = 0;
                $com->save();
            }
            if($usr->delete()) {
                return view('members.delete_account');
            }
        } else {
            return redirect()->back()->with(Toastr::warning('Your Password Was Incorrect!', 'Error', ['options']));
        }
    }
```

This is set up to use Illuminate\Http\Request;

**but i need it to work with Illuminate\Support\Facades\Request;**

Comment: error thrown with code as is:

```
FatalThrowableError in ValidatesRequests.php line 50:
Type error: Argument 1 passed to App\Http\Controllers\Controller::validate() must be an instance of Illuminate\Http\Request, instance of Illuminate\Support\Facades\Request given, called in /home/UNIT3D_2.0/app/Http/Controllers/UserController.php on line 269
```

Comment: You should edit your question and add the error there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at the comment, you imported invalid Request class in your controller. In your controller file you should have :

```
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
```

instead of:

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Request;
```

**EDIT**

If your other function uses already `Illuminate\Support\Facades\Request` you can alias this class like this:

```
 use Illuminate\Http\Request as IlluminateRequest;
```

and then in your `deleteProfile` use:

```
protected function deleteProfile(IlluminateRequest $request) 
{
   // ...
}
```

Comment: yes only issue is other function in my Controller use 
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Request;